# Non-free algorithms stays NO Ubuntu 16.04 opencv-3.4.4

Tags: opencv, cmake, sift, opencv-contrib

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 (clean install) following this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) . Instead of 3.1.0 I tried to install 3.4.6 which did not work, because the Non-free algorithms are not being included. I again tried with version 3.4.4 which again did not work.

The CMAKE file outputs: Non-free algorithms: NO

The CMAKE command I use:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \ 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \ 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \ 
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \ 
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \ 
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/gertjan/opencv_contrib-3.4.4/modules \ 
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

MY whole build file:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX11 (check file: cmake/checks/cxx11.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX11 - Failed
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable exact version "2.7.12") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "3.2") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (found suitable exact version "3.5.2") 
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDATA_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDATA_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDATA_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDATA_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse2.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse3.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSSE3 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_ssse3.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_1 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse41.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MPOPCNT (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_popcnt.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MPOPCNT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse42.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MF16C (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_fp16.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MF16C - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MFMA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MFMA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx2.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx512.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD_MAVX512VL_MAVX512BW_MAVX512DQ (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx512skx.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD_MAVX512VL_MAVX512BW_MAVX512DQ - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_BASELINE_FLAGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_BASELINE_FLAGS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_FP16
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_FP16 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX512_SKX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX512_SKX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for posix_memalign
-- Looking for posix_memalign - found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for memalign
-- Looking for memalign - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so  
-- Found TIFF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (found version "4.0.6") 
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Failed
-- Found Jasper: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (found version "1.900.1") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.2.54") 
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h - found
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Failed
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.18.9
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   Found gthread-2.0, version 2.48.2
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   No package 'libdc1394-2' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   No package 'libdc1394' found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for modules 'libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale'
--   Found libavcodec, version 56.60.100
--   Found libavformat, version 56.40.101
--   Found libavutil, version 54.31.100
--   Found libswscale, version 3.1.101
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- IPPICV: Download: ippicv_2019_lnx_intel64_general_20180723.tgz
-- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
-- at: /home/gertjan/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
-- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
-- at: /home/gertjan/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing:  Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Looking for dgemm_
-- Looking for dgemm_ - found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- Looking for cheev_
-- Looking for cheev_ - found
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH - Failed
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Looking for dlerror in dl
-- Looking for dlerror in dl - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/gertjan/opencv/build/python_loader
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PRIVATE_FIELD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PRIVATE_FIELD - Failed
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.4 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2019-08-09T13:42:29Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.15.0-55-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.5.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (6 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (6 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (12 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (1 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python2 python3 python_bindings_generator shape stitching superres ts video videoio videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java js viz
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.18.9)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.48.2)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.54)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.6)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
--            at:                   /home/gertjan/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
--               at:                /home/gertjan/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/gertjan/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--     numpy:                       /home/gertjan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.16.4)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2)
--     numpy:                       /home/gertjan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.17.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/gertjan/opencv/build
```

All the outputs that failed or packages that are not found

```
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Failed
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   No package 'libdc1394-2' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   No package 'libdc1394' found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing:  Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH - Failed
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PRIVATE_FIELD - Failed
```

I need the non-free algortihms for the use of SIFT.

Comment: Please copy/paste the text for exact error message you are getting, do not attach images of the errors.

Comment: Install FFmpeg, Gstreamer and try to compile again.